# Google OATH with Swagger

Tags: node.js, swagger

I use swagger for my nodejs documentation. I want to test the Google login and basically when go to /auth/google, you should see the google authenication screen screen

```
router
    .route('/google')
    .get(
        checkToken(true),
        passport.authenticate('google', {scope: 'profile email'}),
    )
```

I want to add this route to swagger.

```
/**
 * @swagger
 *
 * /auth/google:
 *   get:
 *     tags:
 *       - Authentication
 *     summary: Google authentication
 */
```

Expectation: Swagger will open the link in new tab and show google login UI
But swagger try to GET the source and show nothing

How to make swagger to open the /auth/google link? Thanks

Update: We can do like this

```
description: Click here [/auth/google](/auth/google) for Google Authentication
```